# understanding passing rails parameters between controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am just starting to wrap my head around parameters in rails. I am currently working on a project that isn't accessible to the public, so keeping params secure isn't exactly a priority in this case.

I have a link_to to a different controller action that requires an object id to fulfil the controller action.

```
  =link_to "Barcode", print_barcode_label_admin_items_path(:item_to_print => { :article_id => article.id })
```

Then in the relevant controller

```
def print_barcode_label
    if params[:item_to_print][:article_id].present? 
    return if force_format :pdf

    ..........
private

def params_document
  params.require(:document).permit!
end
```

As I was writing the code for this controller I am certain the parameters were being passed (I am using the better-errors gem to debug along the way so I could see them being passed in the request parameters hash). But now, not sure what I have done, but i get the error

```
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

failing at line two in my above controller action. I am sure there is something really basic I am missing. What is it? Is there a more favourable way of doing this?

## Update

So I started playing with other possible solutions, and one is naming a route that specifically carries the parameter

```
    get 'print_barcode_label/:article_id', to: 'documents#print_barcode_label', as: 'print_barcode_label'
```

This seems a more robust and sensible approach. Howeever, despite passing the variable in the link, like this

```
      =link_to "Barcode", print_barcode_label_admin_items_path(article.id)
```

Gives a no route matches error

```
No route matches {:action=>"print_barcode_label", :controller=>"admin/documents"} missing required keys: [:article_id]
```

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to answer this question without seeing more code with some context. But if you want to do rails way you should propably create custom action on document resource.

In your routes.rb:

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :documents
    get :print_barcode_label, :on => :member
  end
end
```

And then you can create link to this action:

```
= link_to 'Barcode', print_barcode_label_admin_document_path(article)
```